# To delete a string that ends with repetitive symbol (Python)

Tags: python, string

I have a string 'Iamstillalive:)))'. The task is to delete the smile ':)' or, if it has continuation (more brackets ')'), to delete the smile with them (':)))'). 
How can I delete the smile with any quantity of brackets?

Input:
'Iamstillalive:)))'
Output:
'Iamstillalive'

Input:
'Thecake:))isalie'
Output:
'Thecakeisalie'

Comment: Your title specifies 'ends with' but in your second example the target is in the middle of the string.

Comment: Oh, sorry, thanks for the comment. I meant 'string in string', that ends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub`:

```
inp = 'Iamstillalive:)))'
output = re.sub(r':\)+', '', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Iamstillalive
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import re
s = "Iamstillalive:))))))))))))))"
res = re.sub(r'[$:\)]{2,}', '', s)
print(res)
```

`$` matches end of string

Result:

```
Iamstillalive
```